# Ofstream is closing on its own?

Tags: c++

I am experiencing an odd behavior where I am writing to a file using ofstream and it spontaneously closes in the middle of a loop. I noticed that the file was only writing out for half the loop, so I output the status of the stream throughout the loop and noticed it was closing itself. During this loop, I'm writing to multiple files, and this only happens to one of them, the one that is writing out the least data. I'm going to try to edit and add code but the loop itself is very large (800 lines) so I need to figure out a way to post the required portions.

Until I post code, has this happened to anyone before? Does anyone know of likely, obvious causes I can check for?

Thanks!

Comment: "but the loop itself is very large (800 lines) " - time to refactor methinks...

Comment: Show us your code... and yeah, an 800 line loop is silly.

Comment: About the loop: I'm a scientist, not a software developer. I didn't plan on optimizing my code until the algorithm works- this is also why I'm not sure how much of the code I can actually post. I'll start working on that.

Comment: sometimes the act of cleaning up code to make it understandable leads you to find errors...Please don't confuse optimisation with understandability..  A few well named methods/functions can go a long way...

Comment: Most of the C/C++ code I've seen for running large simulations usually has loops around the 300-500 line size - is this actually unusual and I've just been seeing a lot of poorly written code?

Comment: @MichaelLeVine: Unusual?  Perhaps not.  Poorly written?  Well, hard to understand and follow most likely.  I won't say it's poorly written as it may be good code which works perfectly well. However, I don't want to scan 5+ pages of code and have to remember that I am inside a loop (or two or three...).  Break things out a bit.  I have to imagine there is some repetition in those 800 lines.  As an aside, I am currently in the process of rewriting code originally written by scientists. It works, but...